# I moved the directory of visual studio to a different drive, now I cannot compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My C: drive is strictly for windows (a 64GB SSD), and recently learned that it was nearly full. I changed my program files directory to `D:/ProgramFiles` and all the contents of my old program files to the new directories. Now, trying to compile a program in Visual Studio 2017 Community will give me an error:

`The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found.`

How can I tell visual studio where I moved my files to?

**EDIT**: I have already installed Visual Studio itself (devenv.exe) under "Visual Studio 2K17", but I've moved the assemblies (NOT visual studio) to the D drive. If i choose to reinstall, it will still put files on my C drive.

Comment: You don't.  Uninstall and reinstall onto D.

Comment: As will said. You cannot just "copy" the directory content to another drive and expect it to work. The operating system store information and still thinks its in c. There arev entries on regedit etc.. they must be updated, This happens during installation of applications and true for all installed software.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I tell visual studio where I moved my files to?

By uninstalling Visual Studio and re-install it back and while doing so choose the installation path to `D:\` drive. simply moving the installation directory to different root drive won't make it since there are registry settings which will be still pointing to `C:\` drive installation folder

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Junction folder, I had the same space issue, and I moved all the files to another drive. in case you remember which folders you moved you can still get it working.

Let's say I moved "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET" to "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET"

all I do is in the command prompt(you might need to execute CMD with admin priviledges):

```
mklink /j "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET" "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET"
```

so mklink /j **Dest_Folder SourceFolder**

**Dest_Folder**: where you want your directory junction to appear

**SourceFolder**: where you moved your folder.

Comment: Can I just select the entire C:\Program Files and junction it with the new one? Will it include the subfolders?

Comment: No, there will be folders that'll be in use. Just cycle through the folders and junction the ones that take more than 1gb. also in AppData inside your user folder in c:\Users you will find good candidates to save up disk space.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a repair of visual studio (took roughly 15-20 minutes on a 3MBPS connection), everything was working fine again and everything installed to the new program files directory.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in defining a `Junction folder` using `MKLINK` Dos command.

I used this technic to move `c:\Program Files\dotnet` folder to `d:` drive in same folder name.

Here is my BAT script

```
set folder=\Program Files\dotnet
xcopy /E/H/O "C:%folder%" "D:%folder%"
rename "C:%folder%" "dotnet.$"
mklink /J "C:%folder%" "D:%folder%"
rmdir /S/Q "C:%folder%.$"
```

But to be safe, I executed all these commands manually to be sure that all is working well.

I executed `XCOPY` manually to be sure that all files have been copied.

I executed `RENAME` command manually but it return an error because some files are `IN USE`.

So I used `File LockSmith` from `Microsoft Power Toys` to find locking processes and try to deactive them. Deactivating processes from `File LockSmith` doesn't work because somes services are automatically restarted.
Finally, I use service name returned by `File LockSmith` to deactivate services manually.
When all locking services has been deactivated, I renamed `dotnet` folder manually as administrator.

I executed `MKLINK` manually without problem.

I tested my work during one week without problem.

Then I decide to start `RMDIR` command to free fast 1GB of space.